# Issue resolving initial reference 'NameService'

Tags: redhawksdr

I have followed the install instructions and gone over them multiple times with a fine comb and I am still unable to determine why I cannot resolve the NameService.  I have the omniNames service running, but when I run omniEvents I get the following

```
omniEvents: [32190]: Warning - failed to resolve initial reference 'NameService'. Exception NO_RESOURCES
```

I receive this same error message when I attempt to connect within the Sandbox in the IDE, but I am still able to run components and connect them while running in the IDE Sandbox.

I ran nameclt list and received the following output

`Cannot resolve the root context.
Have you set up the configuration file properly?`

my config file contains the following

```
InetRef = NameService=corbaname::127.0.0.1
InetRef = EventService=corbaloc::127.0.0.1:11169/omniEvents
```

I have also verified that the services are being started on the correct ports using netstat.

What am i missing to get connected to the name service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your error might be due to a typo in /etc/omniORB.cfg.  In your example you use "InetRef" when it should be "InitRef".

Double check the settings and then restart omniNames and omniEvents and try nameclt again.  If you get an error such as this:

```
$ nameclt list
Caught a TRANSIENT exception when trying to validate the type of the 
NamingContext. Is the naming service running?
```

Double check that omniNames is indeed running (i.e. ps -ef | grep omniNames).

Comment: Thank you... missed the typo